# Supervised time series anomaly detection

Tags: time-series, statistics, supervised-learning

I have time series data.
Dataset contains around 600.000 metrics.
Each metric published daily and has three values, let's say 'count', 'number of something', 'length of something'.
Looks this way:

```
name     cnt_2023_05_31 num_2023_05_31 len_2023_05_31 cnt_2023_06_01 num_2023_06_01 len_2023_06_01
m_1      100            1000           10000(bad)     99             1002           10003           
.... 600.000 of such metrics
```

So for each day metric gets three values.

I have historical data where bad metrics are labeled.
For example, length at 2023-05-31 was bad.

I have quite naive approach to catch issues atm. Just set of rules with hand made thresholds.

Rule example:

```
m_1 (metric name) length (values name)
- should not increase or decrease in more than 1% comparing to previous value
- or 
- should not increase or decrease in more than 42 comparing to previous value
```

Ofc, it's hard to maintain such rules since I have to periodically adjust threshold values and %.

My thoughts:

- can I periodically train some sort of ML model using labeled data? I know exactly how bad data points look like. I'm pretty sure there is also a correlation between many metrics. Could it help?
- is there any statistical technique to automatically adjust thresholds in rules? Some sort of standard deviation calculated with sliding window (not good at math :( sorry if it sounds odd)? I've read people using z-score

The ultimate business goals are:

- zero false positives
- zero rule thresholds maintenance.